# AWS Route53 Subdomain Does Not Work All The Time

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am creating an A record for sub domains on my parent domain's hosted zone. The record gets created successfully but when I visit the subdomain it does not resolve to the sub domains ec2 server all the time. It will work for a few tries then not work for a few minutes. When i visit the public IP it always work, it's just when I want to visit the subdomain name. Do I need to add anything else so that is resolves properly?

**My A record info:**

Name: dev.alio.com

Type: A

Value: 52.24.143.16

TTL: 300

Comment: Give us the actual subdomain, so we can take a look.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated it. It's an IP protected website, so you wont be able to access it

Comment: That's fine, I was interested to see if you had two sets of nameservers set up or something. When you get an outage, what does `dig dev.alio.com` output?

Comment: Ahh, that maybe it. I added some nameservers for a subdomain before I migrated the DNS to use route53. So those nameservers must have been imported with the zone file.

Comment: Yes, that's probably it.